# Problem with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I use package `fancyhdr` for make header and footer.

I want to auto quote text in the chapter for right header.

I use : `\rhead{\thechapter}` when latex show for me the number of chapter not text.

Can you tell me : How to show text of chapter on the right header(auto) ? 
Thanks for hint .

Now i have a new problems , if chapter name is very long , i want to have two line in header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle with `\leftmark` and `\righmark`. The example shows you one way. For more information you should read the manual of `fancyhdr`: http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\lhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: chapter name is too long , i want to break line on header? Can you help me?

Comment: @user41499: Rather than doing that, you should use the optional argument of `\chapter` to specify a shorter/compact version of the title: `\chapter[<short title>]{<long title>}`

Comment: @werner I see but i have to do it because that ruler.Thanks werner

Comment: @user41499: You can use a `\parbox` inside`: `\rhead{\parbox{\linewidth}{\leftmark}}`. However you have to recompute the margins.

Comment: I try , before i try to use package calc for auto computes but not win.